# How to interpret pandas value_count() output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe (df):

```
        date                O_3     NO_2        SO_2        PM10        PM25        CO      Label
    0   2001-01-01 01:00:00 7.86    67.120003   26.459999   32.349998   12.505127   0.45    2.0
    1   2001-01-01 02:00:00 7.21    70.620003   20.879999   40.709999   12.505127   0.48    2.0
    2   2001-01-01 03:00:00 7.11    72.629997   21.580000   50.209999   12.505127   0.41    2.0
    3   2001-01-01 04:00:00 7.14    75.029999   19.270000   54.880001   12.505127   0.51    2.0
    4   2001-01-01 05:00:00 8.46    66.589996   13.640000   42.340000   12.505127   0.19    2.0
    ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
139603  2018-04-30 20:00:00 63.00   58.000000   4.000000    2.000000    2.000000    0.30    1.0
139604  2018-04-30 21:00:00 49.00   65.000000   4.000000    5.000000    4.000000    0.30    2.0
139605  2018-04-30 22:00:00 49.00   58.000000   4.000000    5.000000    3.000000    0.30    2.0
139606  2018-04-30 23:00:00 48.00   52.000000   4.000000    7.000000    7.000000    0.30    2.0
139607  2018-05-01 00:00:00 52.00   43.000000   4.000000    6.000000    4.000000    0.30    1.0
```

I want to know the variability of the 'Label' values, hence I:

```
# Variability of 'Labels' values
reshape_df['Label'].value_counts()
```

and I get:

```
2.0    80435
1.0    39393
3.0    15045
4.0     3295
5.0     1440
Name: Label, dtype: int64
```

I add a new column in order to see the maximum value column name on each row:

```
# Create column with max pollutant name
reshape_df['Max_pollutant'] = reshape_df.eq(reshape_df.max(1), axis=0).dot(reshape_df.columns)
```

and I get:

```
date                        O_3     NO_2        SO_2        PM10        PM25        CO      Label       Max_pollutant
0       2001-01-01 01:00:00 7.86    67.120003   26.459999   32.349998   12.505127   0.45    2.0         NO_2
1       2001-01-01 02:00:00 7.21    70.620003   20.879999   40.709999   12.505127   0.48    2.0         NO_2
2       2001-01-01 03:00:00 7.11    72.629997   21.580000   50.209999   12.505127   0.41    2.0         NO_2
3       2001-01-01 04:00:00 7.14    75.029999   19.270000   54.880001   12.505127   0.51    2.0         NO_2
4       2001-01-01 05:00:00 8.46    66.589996   13.640000   42.340000   12.505127   0.19    2.0         NO_2
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
139603  2018-04-30 20:00:00 63.00   58.000000   4.000000    2.000000    2.000000    0.30    1.0         O_3
139604  2018-04-30 21:00:00 49.00   65.000000   4.000000    5.000000    4.000000    0.30    2.0         NO_2
139605  2018-04-30 22:00:00 49.00   58.000000   4.000000    5.000000    3.000000    0.30    2.0         NO_2
139606  2018-04-30 23:00:00 48.00   52.000000   4.000000    7.000000    7.000000    0.30    2.0         NO_2
139607  2018-05-01 00:00:00 52.00   43.000000   4.000000    6.000000    4.000000    0.30    1.0         O_3
```

If I check the variability of 'Max_pollutant':

```
# Variability of 'Max_pollutant' names
reshape_df['Max_pollutant'].value_counts()
```

I get the following output:

```
NO_2           91155
O_3            43166
PM10            4760
O_3NO_2          417
NO_2PM10          48
SO_2              23
O_3PM10           22
PM25              15
O_3NO_2PM10        2
Name: Max_pollutant, dtype: int64
```

I don't quite understand the value counts where two or more pollutants appear. For example, 'O_3NO_2' = 417, does that mean that the maximum value for O_3 is the same as NO_2?

How can I print those row in particularly in oprder to see the readings of each pollutant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those 'strange' values are the result of having the same max value in 2 columns.

You can print them, for example, with:

```
reshape_df.loc[reshape_df['Max_pollutant']=='O_3NO_2']
```

command.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figure it out.